# mergeMap completing too early

Tags: google-maps-api-3, rxjs

I'm using a mergeMap to produce a batch of queries to find out addresses based on points. I map each of the responses to objects in an array.

```
//ptosDistintos = ['-34.5466 58.4363', '-34.5523 58.4486', ...]
this.suscCalcularDirecciones = Observable.from(ptosDistintos)

    .mergeMap(pos => {

        //I convert every position to a latLng object (Leaflet)
        const [lat, lng] = pos.split(' ');
        const latlng = L.latLng(+lat, +lng);

        //I make requests to Google to figure out addresses
        return this.http.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latlng.lat},${latlng.lng}`)
            .filter(x => x.length)
            //I return the address to the mergeMap.
            .map(direccion =>
                [pos, direccion.length ? direccion[0].formatted_address : '(no encontrada)'];
            );
    })
    .finally(() => {

        //I'm deleting the suscription once it is complete because in template I check for completion by checking emptyness of the subscription.
        delete this.suscCalcularDirecciones;
    })
    .subscribe(posDir => {
        const [pos, dir] = posDir;
        for (let i of agrup[pos].indexes) {
            this.historico[i].direccion = dir;
        }
        this.historico = this.historico.slice();
    });
```

However, the observable produced by the mergeMap is completing too early. The "finally" instruction is executed after a few (if not the first) of the "nexts". What can I do to call it after all queries to Google have completed?

Comment: Can you make a demo? The code looks fine to me except `delete this.suscCalcularDirecciones`. You don't need to do this.

Comment: I do because I like to check for completion in the html by checking emptyness of the subscription. I know this won't bring any dificulties if I remove that line. My question refers to why is this happening.

I tried to do a demo but I had problems importing Rxjs in stackoverflow snippet tool. :(

Comment: You can use this template http://jsbin.com/bumeroq/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: When I have some time I will set up a template for demos, right now I don't have an angular one and I need injection. I've been using Plunkr but I don't really like it very much.

Comment: @Umagon Did you try just using the third 'completed' callback of the final observer to delete instead of .finally() ? Or maybe use .takeLast(1) after mergeMap then call finally();

Comment: @Yeysides Yes, I tried that and got the same result. I just got it working by doing something else. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, it was a problem with Google APIs.

```
.filter(x => x.length)
```

This line was removing the responses that had 0 results from google, so the merge was completed with a lot of failures. This is because Google doesn't allow so many requests made per second (I made all of them at the same time, and they were hundreds sometimes).

[image]

I added a timer to the observable so it makes the requests over time.

```
Observable.timer(0, 100)
    .map(i=>ptosDistintos[i])
    .take(ptosDistintos.length)
    .mergeMap(...
```

Hope this helps somebody. I will add the google apis tag.